# Looking to pipe incoming mail with a script and grab contents and store them as variables

Tags: php, email, pipe

Users will send a text message/email to text@domain.com in the form of #### killed #### and we need to take the first #### and store it as a variable, and then take the second #### and store it as another variable.

I can't seem t find any relevant information online that shows what the context of a message looks like if the script were to read it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a very broad question. What are you having trouble with specifically. Fetching emails with php? Parsing text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse a message in a given format with PHP, you could try the following:

```
$text = "abc killed 123";
$tokens = explode(' killed ', $text);
print_r($tokens); // Prints [0] => abc, [1] => 123
```